# How do I have to modify my UIView extension if I wanted to animate the auto layout constraints afterward?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have made an `UIView` extension to set my `NSLayout` anchors. Everything works just fine. But how can I modify my extension if I wanted to add an `NSLayoutConstraint` so I could animate the constraints afterward?

Here is my current extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) {
        //translate the view's autoresizing mask into Auto Layout constraints
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how the extension is called:

```
//feedViewButton constraints
feedViewButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 25), size: .init(width: 50, height: 50))
```

**UPDATE**

I would like to have something like this

```
var topAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

topAnchor = topAnchor.constraint(equaltTo: top, constant: padding.top)
topAnchor.isActive = true
```

And then animate it like this:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeOut) {
    topAnchor.constant = 20
}
animator.startAnimation()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to animate it using autolayout, since the constraints haven't been applied yet, it should be animatable:

```
feedViewButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 25), size: .init(width: 50, height: 50))
feedViewButton.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    feedViewButton.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to later change the constants on the anchors to animate some other change, you have to keep references to the constraints to be able to manipulate them later:

```
enum ConstraintType {
    case top, leading, trailing, bottom, width, height
}

extension UIView {

    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> [ConstraintType : NSLayoutConstraint] {
        //translate the view's autoresizing mask into Auto Layout constraints
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        var constraints: [ConstraintType : NSLayoutConstraint] = [:]

        if let top = top {
            constraints[.top] = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            constraints[.leading] = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            constraints[.bottom] = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            constraints[.trailing] = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            constraints[.width] = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            constraints[.height] = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        }
        let constraintsArray = Array<NSLayoutConstraint>(constraints.values)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsArray)
        return constraints
    }
}
```

This extension returns a dictionary of constraints that you can later change and animate those changes. E.g.:

```
let constraints = feedViewButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 25), size: .init(width: 50, height: 50))
// applies the constraints    
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

// now to animate bottom to -50:
if let bottomConstraint = constraints[.bottom] {
    bottomConstraint.constant = -50
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    animator.startAnimation()
}
```

Comment: Okay. But will it still work with a UIPanGestureRecognizer implemented? So that I can track how far the user moved his finger.

Comment: @JoshSchärer in updated answer I added `. allowUserInteraction` to make sure interaction is enabled. if you want to know if it still works, you can always try it

Comment: I guess it should work, but isn't there a possibility to add an NSLayoutConstraint and then just animate the constraint to another constant?

Comment: @JoshSchärer there is but I dont see how that relates to your question

Comment: I have updated my question. Hopefully, you can now understand how I would like to have it done.

Comment: @JoshSchärer maybe the newly updated answer will be the one you are looking for

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a simple struct to hold and return the constraints?

Comment: @I don't really see any benefit in it, but I don't think it is worse either.. chose whichever you find better

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the animation on the extension, so all calls to `anchor` will be animated without add the animation block always.

```
extension UIView {

    func anchor(animated: Bool, top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) {
        //translate the view's autoresizing mask into Auto Layout constraints
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, but I don't actually want all of my buttons to be animated.

Comment: I updated the code to set optional the animation, if you need a default value you only need to add the default value on funcion declaration like: animation: Bool = true