# mapKit error as Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'anchor'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

```
    var imageView: UIImageView  {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "locationPin")
    return iv
}

//MARK:- Init

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureViewComponents()
}

//MARK:- Helper function

func configureViewComponents() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(imageView)
    // below I am getting error as
```

> Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'anchor'

```
    imageView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 140, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

}


}
```

I tried to implement the popup enable location screen programmatically with an imageview but I am getting the error as "Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'anchor'"

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
 extension UIView {
   func anchor(} {}
 }
```

Found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804325/5820010)

---

```
imageViewtranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(imageView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 140.0 ),
   imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10 ),
   imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200),
   imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
])
```

---

With extension

```
enum ConstraintType {
    case top, leading, trailing, bottom, width, height
}

extension UIView {

    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) {
        //translate the view's autoresizing mask into Auto Layout constraints
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        var constraints: [ConstraintType : NSLayoutConstraint] = [:]

        if let top = top {
            constraints[.top] = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            constraints[.leading] = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            constraints[.bottom] = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            constraints[.trailing] = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            constraints[.width] = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            constraints[.height] = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        }
        let constraintsArray = Array<NSLayoutConstraint>(constraints.values)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsArray)

    }
}

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

     let imageView: UIImageView  =  {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "locationPin")
        return iv
    }()


    // MARK: - View Life Cycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.anchor(top:view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 140, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 200))

    }


}
```

Comment: copy the extension here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804229/how-do-i-have-to-modify-my-uiview-extension-if-i-wanted-to-animate-the-auto-layo/48804325#48804325

Comment: imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0 ).isActive = true

Comment: I copied the extension but if i call imageview.anchor

I find the below code 
imageView.anchor(animated: <#T##Bool#>, top: <#T##NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?#>, leading: <#T##NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?#>, bottom: <#T##NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?#>, trailing: <#T##NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?#>)

Comment: @jawadAli how to setup the paddling top , height & weight ?